# How can i make connection with android applications and external database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

Hi i am trying develope a software in eclipse for android systems. And i really tired to find answer for this question "How can we connect an external database for getting and setting data for android?" i am trying to connect with mysql database and please dont say php files if it is please explain it. I look stackoverflow google i find but not working.
Already Thank You.

[connecting android apps to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530672/connecting-android-apps-to-mysql-database)
like this i coulnt work this and i am trying to find another solution or something right.

Can you help me about this?

Comment: it is in mysql database on my computer.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you not able to _connect_ to your MySQL DB or are you not able to _query_ it?

Comment: i cant connect with each other android and MYSQL database tables

Answer (score 0):

You should use a webservice that runs on your computer to communicate with your database.

Comment: jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
i am trying to connect on this address

Comment: You could also check this tutorial: http://itweb-projects.com/wordpress/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webservice or a servlet running on your computer/server exposed in internet. You will be then able to contact the service via normal http calls to it from your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is to use a web service (i recommend a REST-full web service with [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) cause its simple to use) running on a server on your computer (i.e [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html#top)) to expose the data in the MySQL db.