# Android PHP MySQL Search Results to ListView

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, search

As a preface, I want to say I'm relatively new to the Android application development scene.

I've been working on an Android application which involves a login/registration system which is connected from the Android Application using JSON to PHP script and MySQL. The login/registration is functional but I'm attempting to have an activity which is able to search for registered users and display the results in a ListView on the same xml layout. My PHP script for the search function is functional.

I've looked almost everywhere online to no avail of relevant results. If someone could help me or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is the JSON Parser script I'm using --

public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530672/connecting-android-apps-to-mysql-database) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I'll take a look at the post.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the search is done via AsyncTask, with the results of the search displaying in the ListView of the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to implement is by using the AsyncTask, like below:

```
package <your package>;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            /*BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);*/
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and in your login.java you can use the Async Task to get the user data from the PHP and MySql, below is what i have implemented

notice: you need to learn from it rather than copy the code, because the .xml is different and i don't get the php code here

```
    package com.ecnu.vendingmachine.login;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.ecnu.vendingmachine.MainActivity;
import com.ecnu.vendingmachine.MyApplication;
import com.ecnu.vendingmachine.R;
import com.ecnu.vendingmachine.widgets.JSONParser;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private String Tag = "LoginActivity";

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    private TextView headTitle;
    private EditText loginAccount;
    private EditText loginPassword;
    private Button autoButton;

    private ToggleButton isShowPassword;

    private boolean isAutoLogin = false;

    private LinearLayout registerButton;
    private LinearLayout enterButton;

    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.system_login);

        findViewById();
        initView();
    }

    protected void findViewById() {

        loginAccount = (EditText) this
                .findViewById(R.id.login_account_EditText);
        loginPassword = (EditText) this
                .findViewById(R.id.login_password_EditText);

        isShowPassword = (ToggleButton) this.findViewById(R.id.isShowPassword);
        headTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headbar_Center_Title);

        registerButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_Regist_Button);
        enterButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_Button);
        autoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_Auto_Button);
    }

    protected void initView() {

        headTitle.setText(R.string.login);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        enterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        autoButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        isShowPassword
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        String getPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();

                        if (getPassword.equals("") || getPassword.length() <= 0) {
                        }

                        if (isChecked) {
                            loginPassword.setInputType(0x81);
                            // loginpassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        } else {
                            loginPassword.setInputType(0x90);
                            // loginpassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        }
                        Log.i("togglebutton", "" + isChecked);
                        // loginpassword.postInvalidate();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login_Regist_Button:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.login_Button:
            if (checkPassword() == true && checkAccount() == true) {
                new login().execute();
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }

        case R.id.login_Auto_Button:
            if (isAutoLogin == false) {
                autoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox_focus);
                isAutoLogin = true;
                break;
            } else {
                autoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox);
                isAutoLogin = false;
                break;
            }

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            Log.i(Tag, "pDialog");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String loginAccountText = loginAccount.getText().toString();
            String loginPasswordText = loginPassword.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cellphone", loginAccountText));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginPasswordText));

            // url to create new product
            MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
            String url_login = myApplication.getIP()
                    + "vendingmachine/system_login.php";

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "POST",
                    params);

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    String userID = json.getString("userID");
                    int userIntID = Integer.parseInt(userID);
                    myApplication.setUserID(userIntID);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    private boolean checkPassword() {
        String getPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();
        Log.i(Tag, String.valueOf(getPassword.length()));
        if (getPassword.length() > 5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private boolean checkAccount() {
        String getAccount = loginAccount.getText().toString();
        Log.i(Tag, String.valueOf(getAccount.length()));
        if (getAccount.length() == 11)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```